# If consciousness is a Reification, how does a Buddha attain the Truth?

Tags: secular-buddhism, wrongview, new-age-buddhism

'Reification' is making something real, bringing something into being or making something concrete.

The Pali suttas say about the relationship between consciousness and wisdom/enlightenment:

> *Discernment (wisdom; panna) & consciousness are conjoined, friend, not disjoined. It's not possible, having separated them one from the
>   other, to delineate the difference between them. For what one
>   discerns, that one cognizes. What one cognizes, that one discerns. MN
>   43*

Is the Enlightenment or Wisdom of a Buddha a Reification?

Comment: Isn't that (i.e. "how does a Buddha attain the Truth?") answered in the next line of MN 43 -- i.e., "The difference between these things is that wisdom should be developed, while consciousness should be completely understood"?

Answer (score 1):

**The question make a wrong comparison. It's a totally different story.**

From question's quote, ven. Sāriputta in Ma. Mū. [Mahāvedallasuttaṃ (MN 43)](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/attha/v.php?B=12&A=9220&Z=9419&eng=metta_e1) is talking about minds&wisdoms, which are clinging-aggregates of  run-of-the-mill person before enlightenment; But from question's asking, enlightened minds&wisdoms of Buddha are minds&wisdoms after enlightenment, so Buddha's enlightenment-wisdoms are declung-aggregates of the noble one.

### 1. Question's quote is declung-aggregates:

**Declung-aggregates**  in Sutta. Saṃ. Sa. [issatthasuttaṃ](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=15&A=2773&eng=suttacentral):

> The entire spectrum of an adept’s ethic-**aggregate**, immersion-**aggregate**, wisdom-**aggregate**, ***freedom-aggregate***, and knowledge&vision-**aggregate** of freedom.
>
> Asekkhena sīlak**khandhena** samannāgato hoti, asekkhena samādhik**khandhena** samannāgato hoti, asekkhena paññāk**khandhena** samannāgato hoti, asekkhena vimuttik**khandhena** samannāgato hoti, asekkhena vimuttiñāṇadassanak**khandhena** samannāgato hoti.

**Declung-mind-aggregates** in the end of Sutta. Saṃ. Kha. [Anattalakkhaṇasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/m_siri.php?B=17&siri=59&eng=buddhavacana):

> And while this exposition was being given, the **cittas** of the group of
>   five bhikkhus, by not **clinging**, were liberated from the **āsavas**.
>
> Imasmiñ·ca pana veyyākaraṇasmiṃ bhaññamāne pañca·vaggiyānaṃ bhikkhūnaṃ
>   anupādāya āsavehi cittāni vimucciṃsūti.

**Declung-wisdom-aggregates** and **declung-mind-aggregates** in Sutta. Ma. U. [Mahācattārīsakasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=14&A=3724&Z=3923&eng=suttacentral_2):

> “And what, bhikkhus, is right view that is noble, taintless, supramundane, a factor of the path? The **wisdom(paññā)**, the faculty of **wisdom**, the power of **wisdom**, the investigation-of-states **enlightenment** factor, the path factor of **right view** in one whose **mind(citta)** is noble, whose **mind(citta)** is taintless, who possesses the noble path and is developing the noble path: this is right view that is noble, taintless, supramundane, a factor of the path.

### 2. But question asking about clinging-aggregates:

**Clinging-wisdom-aggregates** in Sutta. Ma. U. [Mahācattārīsakasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=14&A=3724&Z=3923&eng=suttacentral_2):

“[And what, bhikkhus, is **right view that is affected by the taints**, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions](https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/search?q=lokuttar%C4%81)? ‘There is what is given and what is offered and what is sacrificed; there is fruit and result of good and bad actions; there is this world and the other world; there is mother and father; there are beings who are reborn spontaneously; there are in the world good and virtuous recluses and brahmins who have realised for themselves by direct knowledge and declare this world and the other world.’ **This is right view affected by taints**, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions.

**Clinging-mind-aggregates** in Sutta. Tī. Ma.  [Mahāsatipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/pali_read.php?B=10&A=6842&w=%CA%C3%D2%A4%ED_%C7%D2&eng=buddhavacana) Cittānupassanāpabba:

> Here, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu understands **citta with rāga as "citta with rāga"**, or he understands citta without rāga as "citta without rāga", or he understands citta with dosa as "citta with dosa", or he understands citta without dosa as "citta without dosa", or he understands citta with moha as "citta with moha", or he understands citta without moha as "citta without moha", ...

**So, the Enlightenment or Wisdom of a Buddha is a Reification, and the other aggregates as well.**

---

**Note**: **Citta (mind), mano (intellect), and viññāna** (experience/consciousness) **are same**, according to  Sutta. Saṃ. Ni.  [assutavasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/m_siri.php?B=16&siri=57&eng=accesstoinsight_than):

> "But as for what's called 'mind,' 'intellect,' or 'consciousness,' the
>   uninstructed run-of-the-mill person is unable to grow disenchanted
>   with it, unable to grow dispassionate toward it, unable to gain
>   release from it...